# How can use two namespaces in one file?

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am using SDK from http://devbay.net/sdk/guides/api/namespace-DTS.eBaySDK.html
And I need use Finding and Trading services in one file. 
How can i declare different namespaces

```
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Constants;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Services;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Enums;


use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Services;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Enums;
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Services as Services because the name is already in use

So is any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [aliases](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):

```
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Constants;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Services as FServices;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types as FTypes;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Enums as FEnums;


use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Services as TServices;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types as TTypes;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Enums as TEnums;
```

Though to avoid confusion with these newly introduced names, you could fall back to import only `\DTS\eBaySDK\Finding` and `\DTS\eBaySDK\Trading` and explicitly use the types there like this:

```
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Constants;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading;

$fs = new Finding\Services\FindingService();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Namespace 1 {
>                   //your logic 
>   }

Namespace2{
               //your logic

}

Comment: and how can i use in namespace2 logic from namespace1 ? like namespace1/function() ?

Comment: Right, yes same as other namespaces